# Hide formula bar in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to achieve the following:

1. I do not want other users of the sheet to access the formula bar for certain cells/sheets of the spreadsheet
2. I want to block them from accessing the script editor (do not want to show the code) used for this sheet

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I do not want other users of the sheet to access the formula bar for certain cells/sheets of the spreadsheet

This is not possible.
You could publish your spreadsheet but this will not allow to edit any content, or to use Google Forms, but this will allow respondents only to submit data, not to view the result of calculations.

To securely hide the formulas they should be in another spreadsheet. You could use IMPORTRANGE or a script to import/export the calculations result. Bear in mind that IMPORTRANGE isn't recalculated immediately and that scripts could be slower than built-in functions.

An alternative is to create a web app that makes the calculations and call it from a custom function.

> 2. I want to block them from accessing the script editor (do not want to show the code) used for this sheet

It's not possible to block editors to access the Script editor. For details see
[Scripts Bound to Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound). To prevent that viewers get access to the code, block the spreadsheet for making a copy. For details see [Change your sharing settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions per cell:

> ```
> - Click the cell
> - Left-mouse click or Ctrl+click -> menu 'Protect range'
> - Click 'Set Permissions' in sidebar
> - Select Only You
> ```

Now the content is still visible.
There is a work-around for this, which is quite complicated.

```
- Create another sheet, called Formulas.
- Protect this sheet the same way above. 
- In your main sheet you can refer to formulas in the other sheet: =Formulas!B1
- Now you can write the formula in this cell B1 in sheet Formulas
  =Sheet1!B1+Sheet1!C1-Sheet1!D1  (where Sheet1 is the name of the first sheet)
- Now hide the Formulas sheet
```

Comment: Well, its easy to unhide a sheet if the user has edit access right? That may not be the best solution really.. surprised how we cannot hide the formulas altogether in the same sheet without having to create new sheets and reference

Comment: Nope, they cannot unhide it, if you protect the hidden sheet.

Comment: Spreadsheet editors could make a copy of the spreadsheet and unhide sheets on the copy.

Comment: Yes, Ruben, I find that to be a very simple hack. Hence I wanted something more concrete. Something that can control what the user can & cannot do on my sheet. Was hoping for some solution through the Appscript